# Certificate authority public key vs man in the middle attack

Tags: ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption

As I understand, the root of SSL security is based on the public key of certificate authority. And I don't know why this key can be faked by a man in the middle:

The man in the middle received this CA public key but then sends me a public key and fake certificate of his own and pretends that it is valid. I use this key to compute the certificate signature to verify it but if this key is fake, how can I know certificate is not from a trusted source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for any PKI to work, each party should have a list of public keys for CA they trust. These keys have been obtained out of band, securely, from a software vendor.

The SSL certificate (containing the SSL server's public key) received from the server is signed by the private key of one of AC. There is no way to forge a valid certificate without access to one of the CA's private key, so the man in the middle can not send a forged one that  will look valid.

The is two things that we need trust in order to use PKI :
1/ that we can securely retrieve the CA's public keys
2/ that the CA won't mess up by signing forged certificates or by getting their keys stolen.